# My second activity layout doesn't start when I click it

Tags: java, android, android-intent, menu, android-activity

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.colegiul.orar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


         <activity
            android:name=".StartingPoint" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.colegiul.orar.STARTINGPOINT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ourClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

</activity>
           <activity
            android:name=".Menu" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.colegiul.orar.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Menu.java:

```
package com.colegiul.orar;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] ={"StartingPoint", "Clasa a 9-a A", "Clasa a 9-a B"
            , "Clasa a 9-a C", "Clasa a 9-a D", "Clasa a 9-a E", "Clasa a 9-a F"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese =classes[position];
        try{
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.colegiu.orar." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

StartingPoint.java

```
package com.colegiul.orar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/orar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My app is strarting with a splash screen which works perfectly, and opens a new menu, which contains a list with 7 examples and the first one "StartingPoint" should open a new activity, but it doesn't, and my head almost blew up trying to figure out why was that.. can anyone tell my please, why is doesn't work properly? Thanks.

O, PS:
Please be very patient and explain me detailed bacause I am a newbie.

Comment: You forgot to declare the Activities on AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Your `onListItemClick` has something like:

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.colegiu.orar." + cheese);
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

and your manifest has a packaged name defined as: `package="com.colegiul.orar"`.

Obviously won't work!
You should replace the above line by the following one

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.colegiul.orar." + cheese);
```

***EDIT:***

After this, you have another problem instanciating your `Intent` because your `cheese` values are not declared as activities in manifest.

```
String classes[] ={"StartingPoint", "Clasa a 9-a A", "Clasa a 9-a B"
            , "Clasa a 9-a C", "Clasa a 9-a D", "Clasa a 9-a E", "Clasa a 9-a F"};
```

Your `classes` array only contains **one** `Activity` name declared in app's manifest. The others are not. (Actually you can't declare activities with spaces - they are not valid!!) Thus you should be faced with a message in the stacktrace like "Are you declared this Activity in the Manifest" or an exception could be thrown (`ClassNoFoundException`).

Comment: protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  String cheese =classes[position];
  try{
   Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.colegiul.orar." + cheese);
   Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Class.forName(ourClass));

  startActivity(ourIntent);
  }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }


So now ? what I do I have error at forName(ourClass);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you not declare your second activity in your `Manifest`.
For each `Activity`, you need to declare it in your `Manifest.xml` as below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.colegiul.national.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>  
<activity
    android:name="com.colegiul.national.SecondActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" > 
// You declared the Intent-filter as an Activity. This is wrong. An Intent-filter  
// is to inform the system of the capability of the component, not the name of your
// Activity or the package. It is to the say what is your Activity will do.
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>  
<activity
    android:name="com.colegiul.national.ThirdActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And also, as @Vikram said, you need to call your `Intent` like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);  
startActivity(myIntent);
```

You need to set the `Context` at first parameter and the `Class` at the second. See this documentation for more details: [Build Intent Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent)

---

**EDIT:**
In your case, try to create your `Intent` as below:

```
String packClass = "com.colegiul.orar." + cheese;
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Class.forName(packClass));
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

Comment: I declared all activities and if I put ourClass.class, Eclipse says I have to make another class:|

Comment: Damn still not working:| Pressing StartingPoint and it does nothing:(

Comment: You wrong in your `Manifest` (don't know if it's the problem but check my update answer on the manifest)

Answer (score 0):

Two points:
1) put .class after ourClass, while calling ourClass activity. Like this

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass.class);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
```

2) Your second activity is not registered in manifest.xml.Register it like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".ourClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

</activity>
```

Comment: I make both of your suggestions, still not working:(